# How to simulate drop down selection and updated table load with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

I am trying to load through the information about each stock page in investing.com starting from the drop-down list of "Dow Jones Industrial Average" on page [investing.com/equities](https://www.investing.com/equities/)

I have been thinking about using scrapy with

```
options = response.css("select[class=stocksFilter] option[id=166]")
```

but this does not simulate a selection action.

After the selection action, I will be going through the table items one by one in #cross_rate_markets_stocks_1, and crawl those equity pages recursively

Can you point out how to simulate a click action?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection action is user interaction with the browser UI, but **scrapy** doesn't render a webpage, we cannot simulate user interaction or run Javascript with it. However, if you're interested in crawling by simulate user interaction, **selenium** might be a good tool for you.

Back to the question, if we are to crawl with **scrapy**, we should focus on **requests** and **responses** sent to/by the target website, you can log them in the Developer Tools of your browser. After you opened the Developer Tool, click the dropdown menu, you can see the corresponding request is sent to this url:

`https://cn.investing.com/equities/StocksFilter?noconstruct=1&smlID=0&sid=&tabletype=price&index_id=166`

[image: screenshot1]

It's a **GET** request, with `index_id` assigned with selected stock ID, you can get the stock ID and name from HTML element of https://investing.com/equities

```
'xpath of stock ID:   //*[@id="stocksFilter"]/option/@id'
'xpath of stock Name: //*[@id="stocksFilter"]/option/text()'
```